# Adding arrows on 3D curves in Asymptote

Tags: graphics, arrows, 3d, asymptote

I am trying to plot (1D) trajectories in 3D with Asymptote (because I am also plotting surfaces with opacity and do not want to use hacks for hidden surfaces).

Each curve is defined by points in an external `csv` file. The following minimal example for one curve works properly (given a `data.csv` file of course):

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(1,-2,4);
currentlight=(1,-1,1);
size3(200,200,80,IgnoreAspect);

file in=input("data.csv").line().csv();
real[][] a=in.dimension(0,0);
a=transpose(a);

real[] x=a[0];
real[] y=a[1];
real[] z=a[2];

draw(graph(x,y,z),blue,currentlight);

xaxis3(XY()*"$x_1$",Arrow3);
yaxis3(XY()*"$x_2$",Arrow3);
zaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to add arrows on the curve to show the direction of the trajectory.

It seems if the trajectory was a `path`, I could do it quite easily using something such as `draw(pathname,Arrow(Relative(0.7)));`. But I can't manage to "convert" my graph as a curve to do so.

Any ideas how I could add arrows?

I cannot manage to plot arrows on the curves.

Comment: In this case you need to use `Arrow3` instead of just `Arrow`: 
`draw(graph(x,y,z),blue,Arrow3(Relative(0.7)),currentlight);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you need to use `Arrow3` instead of just `Arrow`.
With a simple data file it gives

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0.81,0.59,0.1
0.31,0.95,0.2
-0.31,0.95,0.3
-0.81,0.59,0.4
-1,0,0.5
-0.81,-0.59,0.6
-0.31,-0.95,0.7
0.31,-0.95,0.8
0.81,-0.59,0.9
1,0,1
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(1,-2,4);
currentlight=(1,-1,1);
size3(200,200,80,IgnoreAspect);

file in=input("data.csv").line().csv();
real[][] a=in.dimension(0,0);
a=transpose(a);

real[] x=a[0];
real[] y=a[1];
real[] z=a[2];

draw(graph(x,y,z,operator..),blue,Arrow3(Relative(0.7)),currentlight);

xaxis3(XY()*"$x_1$",Arrow3);
yaxis3(XY()*"$x_2$",Arrow3);
zaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TY. Why did you add the `operator..` in `draw(graph(...),...)`?

Comment: @anderstood: `operator..` was used instead of the default `operator--`
just to make a smooth-looking curve from the included small example data file.
Otherwise it needs to be used with care, since the spline can go wild sometimes.

Comment: Do you know how to adjust the size of the arrow tip?

Comment: `xaxis3(XY()*"$x_1$",Arrow3(size=3bp));`